# How to create a boolean variable in a data set?

Tags: r

How do I create a boolean variable for a dataframe with 2 vectors? I want the boolean variable to identify which one of the objects in vector1 that that are greater than the objects in vector2.

Answer (score 2):

To create a Boolean or logical vector that tests two vectors (or columns in a data frame) we can set up a logical test such as `a > b` which will return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

This output can be assigned to a vector itself as per the example below.

```r
# set seed for random data
set.seed(123)

# create data frame with two random vectors
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10),
                 b = rnorm(10))

# create a logical (boolean) vector
df$c <- (df$a > df$b)

print(df)
#>              a          b     c
#> 1  -0.56047565  1.2240818 FALSE
#> 2  -0.23017749  0.3598138 FALSE
#> 3   1.55870831  0.4007715  TRUE
#> 4   0.07050839  0.1106827 FALSE
#> 5   0.12928774 -0.5558411  TRUE
#> 6   1.71506499  1.7869131 FALSE
#> 7   0.46091621  0.4978505 FALSE
#> 8  -1.26506123 -1.9666172  TRUE
#> 9  -0.68685285  0.7013559 FALSE
#> 10 -0.44566197 -0.4727914  TRUE
```

Created on 2018-09-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

If we are comparing the corresponding elements of two columns

```
with(df1, vector1 > vector2)
```

for comparing each element with all other elements

```
with(df1, outer(vector1, vector2, `>`))
```

Or

```
with(df1, t(sapply(vector1, `>`, vector2)))
```

Comment: How do I get this in the environment window?

Comment: Is there a way to do this by first creating a variable that is false for all objects, and then change it to true for all objects using the == or > logical operator?

Comment: @BatmanTeam  If your example is `df1 <- data.frame(vector1 = c(4, 3, 7, 5, 9), vector2 = c(3, 9, 8, 14, 6))` what should be the expected output